# Install python readline in debian wheezy

Tags: python, debian, readline

I'm trying to install python readline in a new debian wheezy box.

I have installed libreadline-dev
However when I do pip install readline I get following error:

```
building 'readline' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_RL_CALLBACK -DHAVE_RL_CATCH_SIGNAL -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_DISPLAY_MATCHES_HOOK -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_SUPPRESS_APPEND -DHAVE_RL_PRE_INPUT_HOOK -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Modules/2.x/readline.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o -Wno-strict-prototypes

gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o readline/libreadline.a readline/libhistory.a -lncurses -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/readline.so

gcc: error: readline/libreadline.a: The file or folder does not exist

gcc: error: readline/libhistory.a: The file or folder does not exist

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: did you try sudo apt-get build-dep libreadline? and then install as usual with pip

Comment: just tried sudo apt-get build-dep libreadline-dev and the error persists